# How to handle subscribed user for iOS in-app purchase

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I am new to iOS Development.

I am implementing iOS in-app Purchase app using phonegap-plugin.

How to find login user is already subscribed or not?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should record their subscription status in the inAppPurchaseManager's callbacks. Namely,
`window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onPurchased`

If you don't have a backend for your app, I recommend using the [ApplicationPreferences](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ApplicationPreferences) plugin to store the user's subscription state.